# nodejs serve not working responding connection timesout

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have this in my server.js :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write("It's alive!");
      response.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

this works fine on local but not when I deploy it and try access to my `shared.domain.ma:3000` 
In the client side I have a Websocket that trying to connect to my server in that address but it give me `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` ann I tried `curl` and the result is the same again
- What could be reason of this problem?

Comment: Try to change the port to 80 in case there's a firewall. make sure it's not used.

Comment: yes I just checked its the damn firewall .. I cant use 80 or 8080 cuz they are allready used ! How can I forward 3000 to 80 for just this subdomain

Comment: if you are using linux server follow this gist https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/776580

Answer (score 0):

You provided very little info but after some of your comments it is more clear:

> yes I just checked its the damn firewall .. I cant use 80 or 8080 cuz they are allready used ! How can I forward 3000 to 80 for just this subdomain

I think you want to forward 80 to 3000, not the other way around.

You didn't say what server do you use for a reverse proxy. If it is nginx then you can use something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

See this answer for more details:

- [Where do I put my Node JS app so it is accessible via the main website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746124/where-do-i-put-my-node-js-app-so-it-is-accessible-via-the-main-website/40746294#40746294)

Of course you can do the same with Apache, just with different config. Search for reverse proxy config.

Answer (score 0):

You are firewalled, as noted in the comments.
For nginx, check the other answer.
For Apache, use the following configuration, don't forget `a2enmod proxy`:

```html
#/etc/httpd/conf.d/node.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName mydomain
   ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
            
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
   </Proxy>
 
   <Location />
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000
   </Location>
```